# Msal-angular : How to Fetch latest payload after edit profile

Tags: angular, msal-angular

I am facing issue with how to fetch updated user profile information. Right now in chrome Inspect : Application Session storage is showing both information, old first name, last name and after edit profile updated first name, last name. My below script is fetching old info - first name and last name.

Which event i have to use to get latest payload?

I have try below event but not able to fetch.

// SSO_SILENT_SUCCESS

// ACQUIRE_TOKEN_SUCCESS

//HANDLE_REDIRECT_START

// SSO_SILENT_START

//ACQUIRE_TOKEN_START

// ACQUIRE_TOKEN_NETWORK_START

Relevant Code Snippets

```
this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$
  .subscribe((result: EventMessage) => {
    console.log(result);
    console.warn("Home component. LOgin Success");        
    const payload = result.payload as AuthenticationResult;

    localStorage.setItem('IdToken', payload.idToken);
    this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(payload.account);
  });

  this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$
  .pipe(
    filter((msg: EventMessage) => msg.eventType === EventType.SSO_SILENT_SUCCESS)
  )
  .subscribe((result: EventMessage) => {
    console.warn("notification. SSO_SILENT_SUCCESS");        
  });

  this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$
  .pipe(
    filter((msg: EventMessage) => msg.eventType === EventType.ACQUIRE_TOKEN_SUCCESS)
  )
  .subscribe((result: EventMessage) => {
    console.warn("notification. ACQUIRE_TOKEN_SUCCESS");        
  });

  this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$
  .pipe(
    filter((msg: EventMessage) => msg.eventType === EventType.HANDLE_REDIRECT_START)
  )
  .subscribe((result: EventMessage) => {
    console.warn("notification. HANDLE_REDIRECT_START");        
  });

  this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$
  .subscribe((result: EventMessage) => {
    console.warn("notification Remove Pipe");        
  });

  this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$
  .pipe(
    filter((msg: EventMessage) => msg.eventType === EventType.SSO_SILENT_START)
  )
  .subscribe((result: EventMessage) => {
    console.warn("notification. SSO_SILENT_START");        
  });
  this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$
  .pipe(
    filter((msg: EventMessage) => msg.eventType === EventType.ACQUIRE_TOKEN_START)
  )
  .subscribe((result: EventMessage) => {
    console.warn("notification. ACQUIRE_TOKEN_START");        
  });
  
  this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$
  .pipe(
    filter((msg: EventMessage) => msg.eventType === EventType.ACQUIRE_TOKEN_NETWORK_START)
  )
  .subscribe((result: EventMessage) => {
    console.warn("notification. ACQUIRE_TOKEN_NETWORK_START");        
  });
```

Please help.

Comment: Do you even need a filter?, are you sure the `this._destroying$` is not "closed/dead"?

Comment: I have try without pipe and filter but didn't encounter with that scope. See below.

this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$
      .pipe(
        filter((msg: EventMessage) => msg.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS)
      )
      .subscribe((result: EventMessage) => {
        console.log(result);
        this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(payload.account);
      });

    
    this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$
      .subscribe((result: EventMessage) => {
        console.warn("Remove Pipe");
      });

Comment: Still open issue, complete code here. https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/4028